# Floating around images not working at the same time

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having a problem with text floating around an image. See my [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2hvbrqLs/1/#&togetherjs=3MLLirNri7).

If the window is resized to check responsiveness (I used internal styling in JSFiddle to make testing easier on browser) readers will notice that the text on **the left div floats around the image just fine** however on the **right div** titled **construction** lags behind i.e both sides do not float at the same time and I do want them to float at the same time.

Here's a screenshot as well:

[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Agency</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img class="logo" src="./assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>We are a <span>Creative</span> <br/> Design Agency</h1>
    <div class="left card"><img class="tile-image" src="./assets/images/beautiful.jpg" alt="hand and flower in water">
      <h2 class="card-title">Beauty</h2>
      <p class="card-text">We strive to create the most beautiful websites for all your needs. Working closely with you
        to
        design and
        develop an amazing website for your business.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right card"><img class="tile-image" src="./assets/images/construction.jpg" alt="metal structure">
      <h2 class="card-title">Beauty</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Built by our team of professional developers, we ensure the most rigourous and modern websites. Built from
        scratch using HTML and CSS. Only the best for you.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Create. Develop. Design.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

```
/*CSS*/
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: #faf9f6;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  min-height: 95vh;
}

p {
  display: inline;
}

span {
  color: midnightblue;
}


.right > img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.left > img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.left {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

footer {
  text-align: right;
  color: midnightblue;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .left {
   width: 100%;
  }
  
  .right {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  }

  .tile-image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

div > h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

.logo {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

footer > p {
  text-align: center;
}
}
```

One thing that I was able to figure out is that when I change the **h2** from **construction** to a word with **fewer letters** or simply make it idential to "beauty" **in terms of number of letters**, then it starts to work perfectly.

How can I fix this **without changing the H2 title** on the right div?

I expect the float to work at the same time on both divs.

I tried renaming H2 to make it shorter and it started to work fine but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is there much to "explain" here, when there is still just enough space for `Beauty` to fit next to the image, then that same amount of available space will _not_ be enough for the much wider word `Construction`.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty obvious! What's the fix?

Comment: You will need to make both of those `h2` take the same width, by explicitly specifying one.

Comment: Voilà! So I not only specified the width for H2s but also made their display type "inline-block" and they both seem to get along really well now. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The floating works as expected, but the word "Construction" in the right `h2` simply doesn't fit into the line next to the image (it's too wide), so it's moved below it where it fits.

Use a smaller font-size for the `h2` to make the word narrow enough to fit next to the image and/or decrease the `margin-right` for the floated image to create more space on the right side of the image.

Comment: Hey Johannes - Thanks so much for your kind input. I tried both the suggested solutions but the problem persists. I made the recommended changes to the fiddle. Can you please take another look at it for me? 

I know it's easier to just down vote a question than to take the time to figure out the solution so really appreciate your kind attention. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/2hvbrqLs/1/#&togetherjs=3MLLirNri7

Comment: @MarkUsman Well, same answer again: Change the font-size of those `h2` (at least for the screen width where the problem arises, decrease the `margin-right` on the floated image, or/and - third possibility – make the image smaller at the affected window width. Or use a different (larger) width for your media query.

Comment: P.S.: Your fiddle contains the same settings as before: 50px margin-right on the image and no seperate/smaller font-size setting for h2, so no wonder that there is no change...

Comment: Thanks so much! So I specified the width for both H2s and made their display type inline-block and got the desired result. Your hint was SUPER helpful! :)

Comment: the inline-block shouldn't be necessary...